# When will paypal send back the custom variable?

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-buttons

When i add the "custom" variable (with a value of course) to a PayPal subscription Button:

Will it send that custom value with the "profile created" IPN?

With the "payment received" IPN? (Only the first time? each time?)

Both?

With other IPN's associated to this same subscription (when canceling for example)?

PayPal Says:

> User-defined field which PayPal passes through the system and returns to you in your merchant payment notification email. Subscribers do not see this field.

But i don't really understand what it means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the custom field value in every IPN when any action takes for that recurring payment. You will get the IPN in the following cases:
When Profile creates/Payment happens/Profile suspend/Profile canceled.

Comment: Great! thanks. do you know that from experience or from some documentation?

Comment: I found this: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside (which gives the PayPal confirmation to your answer :).